# use URL with query as URL destination

Tags: navigation

I mean can we have something like this? url with double `?` in drupal?

```
http://drupal.org/?destination=xxx/yyy?token=zzz
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort of, but you'll need to URL encode the second `?` otherwise the URL will be invalid.

The best thing to do is use [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) or [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) which will do this for you:

```
$query_string = array('destination' => 'xxx/yyy?token=zzz');
$url = url('<front>', array('query' => $query_string));
```

That will produce the string:

```
/?destination=xxx/yyy%3Ftoken%3Dzzz
```

Which is the correctly encoded version of the URL in your question.

Drupal will also respect this method when auto-redirecting based on a form submission etc. So the page you get directed to will actually look like this:

```
/xxx/yyy?token=zzz
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
http://drupal.org/?destination=xxx/yyy&token=zzz
```